# JQuery ajax success not reading text correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax call to a PHP script, when the PHP script is finished correctly it simply echos "ok".

If it is "ok" I want something to happen, or else something else to happen...

Problem is that the `===` is not matching the text and I get error alert each time although firebug shows me "ok" is being returned and in fact the PHP script is working perfectly.

Here's the JQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/actions/imageUpload.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        if(data==='ok'){
            alert('all is good');
        } else {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
});
```

Why is `if(data==='ok')` failing?

Screenshot below, I changed code to:

```
success: function (data) {
        if(data==='ok'){
            alert('all is good');
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }
```

As you can see it alerts `data` and not "all is good", yet the `data` is "ok"

[image]

Comment: show the php script ?

Comment: When you debug this, what does `data` contain?  Clearly it doesn't contain exactly the string `'ok'`, because I can assure you that logical operators *do* indeed work just fine in JavaScript.

Comment: @David data contains 'ok' - if I alert(data) is simply pops up 'ok'

Comment: Make sure response is "ok", and not "OK" or "Ok". You could try `if(data.toLowerCase()==='Ok'.toLowerCase())` if that's case.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: What happens if you use `==` instead of `===`?  Can you show a screen shot from when you inspect `data` in your debugger?

Comment: @PurpleDroid Checked case, all good

Comment: @david same if use ==

Comment: And what if you print `console.log(data);`

Comment: are you sure its `ok` not `"ok"` may be you can try `if(data==='"ok"')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tTg9T/ seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/actions/imageUpload.php?act_id=<?=$act_id?>',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        if(typeof response == typeof 'string'){
            if( response == 'ok')
                 alert('all is good');
             else
               alert('error:');
        } else {
            alert('error: Type Mismatch');
        }
    }
});
```

You can remove the line `typeof response == typeof 'string'` once you test it.

Comment: But that will fail on response === 'ok' like it's doing now, so typeof is redundant

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Thanks for suggestions. ohh yeah, Let me update.

Comment: OK, I'll accept that as it doesn't answer the question but starts another as it is a type mismatch somehow - thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear you bro! That's the Rubber duck debugging technique :) Its truly required to a javascript developer ;) :)